# Event emitter between files not working with ES6 import/export and worker_thread

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, eventemitter, worker-thread

I have two files, first is `state.js` which you might see below:

```
import EventEmitter from "events";
import tasklist from 'tasklist';

export const stateManager = new EventEmitter();

//IIFE working every 10 seconds via cron task, from the file below
(async () => {
  const processes = await tasklist();
  const exist = processes.find(({imageName}) => imageName === 'process.exe');

  if (!!exist) {
    console.log(!!exist)
    stateManager.emit('state', 1);
  } else {
    console.log(!!exist)
    stateManager.emit('state', 0);
  }
})();
```

The second is the `eventListener.js` file, which running endlessly.

```
//import stateManager from first file
import { stateManager } from "./src/controller.js";

/**
 * Here is part of the code
 * which starts the first file
 * as a Worker cron-task every 10 seconds
 * It doesn't block the thread.
 */
const bree = new Bree({
  logger: logger,
  jobs: []
});
bree.add({
  name: "state",
  interval: ms("10s")
})
bree.start();


// First listener
console.log('check');
stateManager.on('state', function firstListener(...args) {
  console.log('State updated', args);
});
```

After I launch the `eventListener.js`, the output which I see in the console is the following:

```
check
false
State updated [ 0 ]
 [LOGGER]  21-03-01 18:03:67  info : Worker for job "state" online
false
 [LOGGER]  21-03-01 18:03:08  info : Worker for job "state" exited with code 0
 //every 10 second then =>
 [LOGGER]  21-03-01 18:13:69  info : Worker for job "state" online
false
 [LOGGER]  21-03-01 18:13:06  info : Worker for job "state" exited with code 0
```

or if I export `export const stateManager = new EventEmitter()` from another (third file) not the `state.js` directly.

```
check
 [LOGGER]  21-03-01 18:03:23  info : Worker for job "state" online
false
 [LOGGER]  21-03-01 18:03:63  info : Worker for job "state" exited with code 0
 //every 10 second then =>
 [LOGGER]  21-03-01 18:13:23  info : Worker for job "state" online
false
 [LOGGER]  21-03-01 18:13:63  info : Worker for job "state" exited with code 0
```

So the task works fine, and the event listener never ends, but somehow, it doesn't react to `state` event or react only once, at the begining. Why such a problem could be? Since I have no other error in the console?

> *If it helps, I use `bree.js` as a job queue manager, which actually runs the cron-task itself.*

### Solution

I guess I have found the solution to the problem, but I couldn't understand the reason itself.

In my case, it's better to use not the `events` library, but `worker_threads`, so the code now looks like that:

```
import { parentPort } from "worker_threads";
import tasklist from 'tasklist';

//IIFE working every 10 seconds via cron task, from the file below
(async () => {
  const processes = await tasklist();
  const exist = processes.find(({imageName}) => imageName === 'process.exe');
  if (parentPort) parentPort.postMessage({ state: !!exist })
})();
```

and the `eventListener` receive side looks like:

```
bree.on('worker created', (name) => {
  bree.workers[name].on('message', (message) => {
    console.log(message);  // Prints { state: !!exist }
  })
});
```

So the messages from the first file have been delivered successfully.
But I'll be very glad if someone, will explain it to me, why `events` library can't deliver messages between different works, even if the `eventListener` has been exported correctly.

Comment: Where is the `async` IIFE being done every 10 secs?

Comment: If has been added to the job queue, via [Bree](https://github.com/breejs/bree)

Comment: Why don't you add a `try/catch` inside that `async` function. Or a `catch` handler after invocation.

Comment: @MinusFour it has nothing to do with `try/catch` blocks themselves. I have found that it's relative to the worker_thread library and using of the `Bree`. So I have updated my question.

Comment: It just doesn't make sense to me that it's not printing `check` every 10 seconds. That probably means that `Bree` is doing something weird then.

Comment: Well, maybe, that's why I am asking. If I knew the answer, I won't start the question. But according to the Bree job instance, it's every file launched is a just a `Worker` class instance, and is capable to send/receive messages via `messagePort`

Comment: You said that just the IIFE was being scheduled every 10 seconds. How did you do that? This would have been much easier if we had the `bree` code.

Comment: @MinusFour I have updated the question, with the following code. There is nothing especial actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bree` basically starts a new process. What you got there is the equivalent of doing:

```
node eventListener.js
```

And then:

```
node state.js
```

Every 10 seconds. There's an Event Emitter being created every 10 seconds but there's no listener attached to it, because that's on your `eventListener.js` file which isn't being run, just `state.js` every 10 seconds.

Bree might be overkill for this, you could just use `setInterval` or a `setTimeout` loop. These are `async` anyway and you aren't doing anything heavy on the JS side so you shouldn't be blocking as much. Though if you do want to use workers, your solution seems OK to me. Might be easier to just work with workers directly and forgo `Bree`.

Another option would be to set up `Bree` with `eventListener` on a separate file. You just run that other file (which will run all your program every 10 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Seems I understand the reason for such behavior, but I am not sure that it's the Bree issue itself.

Just don't use the IIFE function as a build-in cron-task of Bree. Instead of that, use the cron-task inside the file. Doesn't matter how exactly you'll do it, via `await sleep(time)` and recursion, or via the node-scheduler module itself.